# Wrong return url in Yii framework

Tags: php, url, yii

I have used `Yii::app()->user->returnUrl` but it always redirect me to `localhost/index.php`. Is there any particular configuration or some pieces of code that other programs that I must write? If you have another solutions let me know it.

Answer (score 3):

@aslingga, can you please explain what you're trying to do with returnUrl? Are you just trying to get back to where you were after logging in, or are you using it somewhere else?

This is from the [Yii documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser#loginRequired-detail):

> Redirects the user browser to the
>   login page. Before the redirection,
>   the current URL (if it's not an AJAX
>   url) will be kept in returnUrl so that
>   the user browser may be redirected
>   back to the current page after
>   successful login. Make sure you set
>   loginUrl so that the user browser can
>   be redirected to the specified login
>   URL after calling this method. After
>   calling this method, the current
>   request processing will be terminated.

In other words, if the page you're trying to request requires authentication, the URI of the page you're on gets stored in a session variable. Then, once you've logged in, it takes you back to that page.

One way I'd recommend troubleshooting is to do a `print_r($_SESSION);` just to make sure the returnUrl is actually being stored. Then you'll be able to check if index.php is being stored as returnUrl or if you're just being redirected there for some reason.

Looking at the CWebUser methods getState and setState might also be helpful.

Comment: I want to change my language from default EN_US to ID_ID. Like this url => http://www.domain.com/language/change/to/id_id. So after I change my language it will redirect to my last page. Do you have another solution? Let me know it.

Comment: @aslingga, in response to your comment on @addfs' post. You can obtain the page the user is on via one of the CHttpRequest class methods. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpRequest#url-detail. Which are wrappers for the php $_SERVER variable.

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is old but maybe this will help someone out since I didn't couldn't find a decent answer anywhere.

## How getReturnUrl works

Setting a default return URL for your Yii app requires a bit of customization. The way it works out of the box is that you specify the default return URL each time you call it:

```
Yii::app()->user->getReturnUrl('site/internal');
```

The idea being that if a user were to visit a page that requires authentication, they will get redirected to the login page, but not before the site running

```
Yii::app()->user->setReturnUrl('site/visitedpage');
```

Now when the user logs in, they will be returned to the page they intended to go to.

While I like that functionality, having to set the default return URL each time is dumb. If you want to change the default return URL, you have to go find it throughout your code. I suppose you could set the value in a site parameter and call

```
Yii::app()->user->getReturnUrl(Yii::app()->params['defaultReturnUrl']);
```

I don't think I have to explain why that solution is annoying too.

## My Solution

So when **getReturnUrl** is called without any parameters, it returns either '/index.php' or just '/'. This is fine in some cases, but not always. This is better IMO.

First, extend the **CWebUser** class and add the following extras

```
class WebUser extends CWebUser {
    // default return URL property
    public defaultReturnUrl;

    // override the getReturnUrl method
    public function getReturnUrl($defaultUrl=NULL) {
        if ($defaultUrl === NULL) {
            $defaultReturnUrl = $this->defaultReturnUrl;
        }
        else {
            $defaultReturnUrl = CHtml::normalizeUrl($defaultUrl);
        }
        return $this->getState('__returnUrl',$defaultReturnUrl);
    }
}
```

Now, let's add a couple items to the **user** component array.

```
'user' => array(
    'class' => 'WebUser',
    'defaultReturnUrl' => 'site/internal'
)
```

Not only does this allow you to set a default return URL in the config, but also maintains the ability to set a different default return URL and use the setReturnUrl functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you must set it:

```
Yii::app()->user->setReturnUrl('controller/action');
```

Comment: But I don't know clearly the current url being accessed by the user.